# Ctrl-] to open relevant help straight from .vimrc

Tags: vimrc, help-system, tags

I am trying to get use the help files more, and therefore I would like to make so I can just put the cursor over a setting in my `.vimrc` and press `Ctrl-]` to open the relevant section in the help files.

If I e.g. write `:help nocompatible`, it brings up the relevant help section. However, if I move my cursor over the word `nocompatible`

```
set nocompatible
         ^
         |
     my cursor
```

and I press `ctrl-]` then I get the error messages:

```
E433: No tags file
E426: tag not found: nocompatible
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I've had a look at http://superuser.com/questions/515699/vim-errors-e433-no-tags-file-e149-no-help-for-help-txt but it doesn't pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I think the functionality you want is very useful, but it is already provided with the `K` mapping. This runs a program to lookup the keyword under the cursor. By default, it uses `man`. You can set it to `':help'` (or to `''`) to open vim help files with `K`.

Note that this is very useful, as it can be used to set a different lookup program for different file types. Thus, if you set it up, you can use `K` to consistently lookup the desired manual or help files.

References:
- `:h K`
- `:h 'keywordprg'`
- [Discussion on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/3oo1e0/has_anyone_found_a_way_to_make_k_useful/)

Comment: I saw the `K` command, but wasn't sure how to make it use `:h`. It looked like it uses external programs.

Comment: I use this to tell `K` to use Vim help when I'm editing Vim files: `autocmd BufReadPost {.vimrc,*.vim} setlocal keywordprg=:help` I'm not sure why that isn't a default!

Comment: @joeytwiddle Sounds like a job for a `FileType` autocmd

Comment: You're right @muru. It now looks a bit cleaner: `autocmd FileType vim setlocal keywordprg=:help`

Answer (score 2):

The help system's tag files are probably present, but loaded only for the `help` system. You could probably define a mapping, like:

```
nnoremap <c-]> :exec "h " . expand("<cword>")<cr>
```

`<cword>` contains the word currently under the cursor, so we use `expand?("<cword>")` to get its value and run the `:h[elp]` command on it.